# CSRF Prevention with Referral Header

Tags: security, csrf

I am new in security topics and I have a message that says :

```
"Validate the value of referrel header and use 
 one time nonce for each submitted form."
```

Basically the jsp page contains basic redirection logic. it does not check referrel header at all, it only decides according to user agent where to redirect.

My jsp page:

```
 if user-agent is IE then redirect to page X
 else redirect to page Y
```

What is the correct way to secure the page? Can I just check referrel header and decide if it should be redirected or not ?

Comment: "I have a message that says" — A message from whom? Ask them to justify it.

Comment: "if user-agent is IE then redirect to page X else redirect to page Y" — All else being equal, I see no reason that needs any kind of CSRF protection or need to care about the referer header (there is no such thing as a referral header).

Comment: message is coming from our security scanner system, it is false positive as you mention no need to protect anything as it does not post anything.